# What does time-taken on IIS 10 logs measure, in the context of a .NET application?

Tags: .net, iis

I would like to understand the correct way to interpret the value of the `time-taken` property that can be found on IIS 10 logs, particularly in the context of a hosted .NET application. I have both Full Framework and .NET Core applications hosted in IIS 10.

The best documentation i can find refers to IIS 6&7, and has no mention of .NET: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/944884/description-of-the-time-taken-field-in-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-http-loggin

I'm particularly interested in knowing if TCP buffering would be used by .NET, so I can understand if the values in `time-taken` are sensitive to client network conditions.

Comment: Neither .NET Framework nor .NET Core performs TCP/IP on its own, but delegate that to Windows. So "if TCP buffering" is used by Windows, it applies to .NET Framework/Core above. To gain more insights into the timing, you'd better use tools like Wireshark on both client/server side to capture the network packets for further analysis. IIS log files can provide some info, but really limited.

Comment: @LexLi The Microsoft article I linked to says that TCP buffering 'may' be used if a flag is passed to `HTTPAPI.dll` by the application. I expect either the .NET framework always does or does not set this. Or perhaps has its own conditions for deciding whether to set it.